# Software for character management for the pen & paper RPG GURPS, Edition 3

Tags: information-management, rpg

Let me start with a little bit of backstory:

My RPG-group decided to play [GURPS Lite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GURPS_Lite). Since we are from Germany we decided to play the German version, which only is the third edition of [GURPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GURPS). Sadly it is the only one available in German and not all of my players are fluent enough in English to read the rulebooks.

So I looked around for a software to manage the characters but only found some for GURPS, fourth edition. The rules changed in essential places for characters so I can't use it.

Features:

1. Managing several characters for GURPS 3
2. Managing skills
3. Managing attributes
4. Managing advantages/disadvantages

Preferably:

5. Managing character points
6. Managing posessions
7. Managing connections to NPCs

Could be in English or German.

Should be available for Linux or Windows. Can also be a web app.

My budget would be about 30$.